# c# cast creating unwanted properties

Tags: c#, casting

[image]

I have an interface

```
public interface IHaveCreateDate
{
    DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

Next, I have a class
    public class Dog
    {
    }

Now, my dog, does not have a create date. If I cast my dog to IHaveDate, I'm able to see a value:

```
((new Dog()) as IHaveCreateDate).CreateDate //Displays: {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}
```

I expected that since dog does not have a CreateDate, it cannot be casted to IHaveDate, and thus the cast should return a null. But instead, the cast "creates" a new property, initializes it to its default value, and then assigns to the object. Can anyone point out to where the c# documentation suggests this behaviour? I read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) and could not find anything implying this or related.

UPDATE:

I think I figured out what is happening, but just to provide an explanation, adding a screen shot of what I was seeing.

So, I was looking at this target object, which did not have the LastModifiedDate property, as can be seen in the watch window.

But the cast to IDateVersionedEntity interface (which only has one date property), succeeded. And this got me confused that if LastModifiedDate is itself not even a property on target object, where is it coming from.

Turns out that waayyy.. before this method is invoked, target used to be an object which had this property, but was casted down to other interfaces that no more exposed it. Should have been obvious! So my bad. Thanks for your time.

Comment: it is because datetime is valuetype, use nullable datetime

Comment: Are you seeing this in the debugger or are you actually allowing the program to run (which should crash)?

Comment: I would've expected an InvalidCastException here as well.

Comment: Please show the declaration of `Dog`. `((new Dog()) as IHaveDate).CreateDate` will throw an `NullReferenceException` if `Dog` does not implement `IHaveDate` since `(new Dog()) as IHaveDate` will return `null`.

Comment: I can not re-create your issue https://dotnetfiddle.net/qSXp95

Comment: The interface is named `IHaveCreateDate` and you used `IHaveDate`. When I run it with the right interface I get `NullRefernceException` meaning the cast returned a `null`

Comment: @crush `as` does not throw an exception (unless the .NET runtime is hopelessly lost in catastrophic failure land), it will merely return `null` if the object does not in fact implement/inherit from the other type.

Comment: To answer your question, the C# specification, and compiler, and runtime does not support the described functionality, other than what you hint at with a nullreferenceexception. As such, either you're not really executing the code you think you're executing, or the type actually does implement the interface. `as` will definitely not add properties or interface implementations to an existing class.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I guess that's why I never use `as`. It just doesn't ever seem like a good idea to me. Why would I prefer to get a null from a casting error, instead of having an exception thrown?

Comment: Renaming interface to `IHaveDate` the cast results in `null` what's the definition of `IHaveDate`

Comment: @crush On the contrary, it is a very good idea. You can do this: `var disposable = someObject as IDisposable; if (disposable != null) disposable.Dispose();` This will do 1 cast, not two. This code becomes even shorter in C# 6.0: `(someObject as IDisposable)?.Dispose();` still 1 cast, not 2.

Comment: The actual code has a number of additional interfaces... let me update the question with a more accurate picture of what I'm seeing

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Okay, sure I've done that. I just don't usually write code where I don't know if an object inherits an interface or not. I'm usually working with an interface already. I just usually don't write code where I have conditional logic that runs only if an object is of a specific type of interface. I guess it can be useful, but I routinely see people using it in place of explicitly casting.

Comment: The only places I tend to do casts is precisely when I don't know if an object implements an interface or not. If I have to do casts between object types in other parts of the code it usually means I'm using some assumptions that the compiler can't verify or provide me with, so something is designed wrong.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Sure, implicit casting is king. I just can't remember the last time I've used `as` outside of the IDisposable you mentioned. Dependency Injection and the interfaces I create usually restrict me from being in situations where I don't know if an object implements a specific interface because it is already the interface I need. I'll just leave it at that.

Comment: Please show a screenshot of what you're seeing so that we can fully understand where/how you're observing that date.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to add anything to a class by casting: you interpreted a bug in a debugger incorrectly.

Once you apply operator `as` to a `Dog` which does not implement the desired interface, you immediately get a `null`. From that point on, any attempt to reference a field of off the result of a failed cast will result in a crash ([demo](http://ideone.com/O4PpiU)).

However, debugger is lenient, so rather than reporting a crash to you, it produces the default value of `DateTime`, a value type.

Comment: How would the debugger be lenient, when I run `.CreateDate()` the cast is null resulting in `null reference exception` the debugger doesn't have time to be lenient

Comment: Where in the debugger do you observe this behavior? I get NullReferenceException everywhere I try it, watches, quick watch, immediate window. Granted, this is Visual Studio 2015, but I've never seen this behavior.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I similarly cannot get anything to appear in CreateDate in VS 2010 or VS 2013. My guess is that the asker is misreading the debugger and sees something like this: http://i.imgur.com/W6e2Cyg.png  That, or he is not giving us the correct information in the question.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Yes, that actually seems likely.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `Dog` class inherits from a class that has the `IHaveCreateDate` interface implemented?

```
public class Dog : Animal
{}

public class Animal : IHaveCreateDate // IHaveBirthDate would be more suitable here ;-)
{
    DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```